# Plantear funcion recursiva suseción fibonacci en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio en javascript:

> Podemos programar usando recursividad otras muchas sucesiones que se
> nos puedan ocurrir, como la siguiente:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Programa la función recursiva anterior. A continuación, escribe un
> programa que pregunte un número al usuario (el usuario debe
> introducirlo por teclado, asegúrate de que el valor introducido es
> numérico y mayor que 0, en caso contrario debes volver a preguntar el
> número, puedes usar aquí un bucle while) y devuelva el valor de
> nuestra sucesión para ese número

No entiendo bien como plantear la función donde numero es la variable introducida, creo que es numero=1 sería 2, numero=2 sería -3, numero=3 sería -6 y así, pero como lo puedo traducir a una función recursiva?

Adjunto mi código

```
var numero=prompt("Introduce un numérico y mayor que 0")*1;
var contador=0;
var var1=0;
var var2=0;

function fibonacci() {
  if (i<numero) {
    var numero=var1+var2;
    var1=var2;
    var2=contador;
    i++
  }
}
```

Comment: Si te dicen que uses funciones recursivas es porque tienes que usar parámetros y no variables globales. `var` hace eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes saber que con `var` defines variables globales y con `let` variables locales. Además, el enunciado te dice que es una sucesión y no específicamente la de fibonacci.

---

Leyendo la imagen, la función `S` tiene una entrada (`n`) y hay una salida que varía según el caso:

- Si `n` es 1, la salida es 2.
- Si `n` es 2, la salida es -3.
- Si `n` es mayor a 2, la salida es `S(n - 1) * S(n - 2)`.

Llevar esto a código es fácil.

```
function s(n){
    if(n == 1)
        return 2

    if(n == 2)
        return -3

    if(n > 2)
        return s(n - 1) * s(n - 2)
}
```